# Server-side React with pure components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux, isomorphic-javascript

I am trying to build an isomorphic React app that adheres to best practices. I am currently only trying to find a good system for the server. Here are some of my requirements:

### Requirements

- I want to use [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router)
- I am trying to avoid a flux-architecture, because it is overkill for my simple app
- I want my React components to be pure, so they should not store model data in their internal states
- React components should also **not** fetch the data they need themselves, this data should be passed to them through `props`
- If a component requires data to be loaded asynchronously, that should happen on the server before the render

### Simple Sample Application

I made a little  sample application that is supposed to illustrate my problems/confusion: https://github.com/maximilianschmitt/ipman

Basically, the **component tree** looks like this:

```
RouteHandler
  App
    RouteHandler
      Home
      Ip
```

**routes.js**

```
'use strict';

const Router = require('react-router');
const App = require('./components/app');
const Home = require('./components/home');
const Ip = require('./components/ip');
const Route = Router.Route;

const routes = (
  <Route handler={App}>
    <Route name="home" path="/" handler={Home} />
    <Route name="ip" path="/ip" handler={Ip} />
  </Route>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

**components/ip.js**

```
class Ip extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Your ip is: {this.props.ip || 'undefined'}</div>;
  }
}
```

### My Question/Task is:

- If I navigate to `/ip`, I want the server to request its own ip address from http://ip.jsontest.com, somehow pass it through to the `Ip` component and then render everything down to a string for the client to see as HTML.
- I think I want to avoid making HTTP requests inside components, I want to instead pass through the necessary information through `props`

I understand that libraries such as [alt.js](http://alt.js.org/) and other isomorphic flux-implementations solve this through the concept of stores but I'm wondering if this is not a bit overkill.

Is there a simple way to add the desired functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I got something working that seems like not such a bad solution, based on [this article from react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/wiki/Announcements#whats-the-deal-with-the-new-api). You can find the results here: https://github.com/maximilianschmitt/server-side-react